# Creating Batch Spectrograms Using FFMPEG?

Tags: audio, command-line, ffmpeg, windows-10, spectrogram

So I am wanting to create spectrograms using the FFMPEG for thousands of FLAC files in batch.

I am using the following for just one file.

```
ffmpeg -i audio-in.wav -lavfi showspectrumpic image-out.png
```

However, I would like to do this for all the files in a certain folder (\Desktop\FLACfiles) and don't want to keep changing the file name and the image output name.

I would like to somehow create a batch script in Windows 10 that automatically creates a spectrogram based on the filename.

I was trying to make it work but I don't have much experience via command line or programming in general. Not sure how to do achieve this.

Simply put, would like to use commands from a working directory containing FLAC files and create a spectrogram for each file matching the filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me using mp3 files but it wasn't fast. Someone may have a better solution. Try this as a bat file.

```
for %%a in ("*.mp3") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -lavfi showspectrumpic "%%~na .png"
```

Comment: This does the job. It seems like it takes a while but this can be avoided if you are willing to lower the resolution. The default resolution is 4096 x 2048 so I simply just changed to 1920x1080 and it took 25.5 seconds to process 10 FLAC files as opposed to an entire minute. The command used is `for %%a in ("*.flac") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -lavfi showspectrumpic=s=1920x1080 "%%~na.png"` Thank you for the help.